# Windows 7 constantly dropping wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My wireless connection drops every couple of minutes. It's in this constant cycle of connecting and disconnecting. It's extremely frustrating.

My computer is the only one on the network that is having this problem. I just moved home from school for the summer, and wasn't having any trouble with my wireless network at school (it's an identical setup -- same router hardware). My drivers are up to date.

I always get this event in event viewer:

> The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service was successfully sent a stop
>   control.
>
> The reason specified was: 0x40030011 [Operating System: Network
>   Connectivity (Planned)]
>
> Comment: None

I've tried:

- rebooting the router
- disabling the Computer Browser service (there were events stating that a forced re-election occurred)
- disabling NetBIOS (I still get the NetBIOS events)
- disabling 802.1x authentication on the router
- disallowing the power saver to shut off the network adapter
- booting in safe mode
- deleting network profile information
- resetting IP stack
- changing the wireless channel on the router

Nothing has had any effect whatsoever. My connection was working fine yesterday, and there haven't been any changes to my PC since then.

Please help me stop all my hair from falling out :(

Comment: Looks like you've already seen [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-randomly-drops-the-tcpip-netbios-helper/a5e0a261-8344-45b2-af3a-75a45332a2ed) MS forum topic related to this event. I also ran into this event. After digging with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I found in my case that `netsh` commands were being executed, which was causing this service to be restarted.  Probably not what's going on in your case, but you might also look for any utilities or scripts executing `netsh`.

Comment: @nondescript1 It sounds like a problem that has a huge number of causes. Whatever it was, it wound up going away on its own, so I guess I have no way of investigating further. I don't really know what to do with this question now, I suppose I can just leave it open in case anyone has some new information about it that can be added.

Answer (score 1):

Win 7 random power dropouts - I found that the powersaving settings on my laptop, when connected to power (as opposed to when only on battery), were causing the problem, so on my custom power, I set everything to maximum performance and anything requiring numbers (time) I set at 9999. Remembering to select my default at Custom Power.  The wifi network has been stable ever since.